# 'OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.Models.User', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.Models.Repository'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I may be asking a question that a lot of programmers might have asked but still here it goes..

I have the a model User with following properties

```
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public int userTypeID { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public long phoneNumber1 { get; set; }
    public long phoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
```

In the action `UserProfile()` I load an object named user with a user's details as shown above and send it to the view as

```
View(user);
```

And I have created a strongly typed view as

```
@model OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserProfile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>UserProfile</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.firstName)
    </div>
    .
    .
    </fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

When I execute the application and redirect to the view it showing the following error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type **'OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.Models.User', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.Models.Repository'.**

Can any one help out on where I went wrong?

Thanks for any support in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever controller action you are redirecting to accepts a `Respository` model but not a `User` model as its parameter. Is that enough information to fix the problem?

Comment: No it's not working, I created a strongly typed view for User and now Repository, and I am sending an object of User to the view but still it's showing this error..

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the view that the controller is trying to show? There is no mention of a `@model Repository` anywhere in the razor code you showed.